# Unable to persist a deep nested Entity with newly created relations (Doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, associations, persistent

I have one entity "User" and it has other relations :
"posts" and underneath "posts" I have another relation called "comments".

Now I want the user to be able to post to the endpoint like this:

```json
{
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "posts" : [
   {
     "Title" : "Main post",
     "comments" : [
       {
          "body" : "Love this post!"
       }
     ]
   } 
  ]
}
```

And therefore allow to make all the objects in one call.
The thing is that everything works deeply enough till the point that we have to save the comments part.

I've already tried the following:
in the User model I set "postComments" with the following annotation constructor.

```php
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Posts", mappedBy="comments", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $postComments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postComments = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

class Post {
     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist","remove"})
      *
      * @Assert\Valid
      */
    private $comments;
}
```

And in the repository I tried this:

```php
  foreach ($comments as $comment) {
            $newComment = $this->commentRepository->create($post,$comment);
            $post->getComments()->add($newComment);
        }
```

And I tried

```php
$post->setComments($newCommentsArray)
```

All gave the same problems as ofcourse the ID of the "post" isn't created yet and therefore the relation can't be set, but how can we solve and do this with Doctrine?

Or is there a limitation

This together will give the following problem:

```
App\Entity\Comments is missing an assigned ID for field 'postId'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.
```

Comment: Did you try `$post->setComment($comment)`? Also can you edit your question to add `Comment` entity and Post setters

Comment: Tried it and fixed it. The problem was that it the comment id was a composite primary key. This still seems to be a problem in Doctrine so I changed the composite key and added a new primary key. This including your answer helped to solve it.